# Why is my Union Find Disjoint Sets algo for this problem not passing all test cases?

Tags: java, algorithm, disjoint-sets, union-find, disjoint-union

Sample input:

```
1
3 2
1 2
2 3
```

First line = # of test cases

First number of second line = number of people

Second number of second line = number of friendships, F

Following F lines = the friendships

Output would be the size of the largest friend group.

So, sample output for that input would be 3. ([1, 2, 3])

My solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tests = reader.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
            int numcitizens = reader.nextInt();
            // the input is 1-indexed so I create the parent array as such
            int[] parent = new int[numcitizens + 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < (numcitizens + 1); j++) {
                parent[j] = j;
            }
            int[] rank = new int[numcitizens + 1];
            int numpairs = reader.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < numpairs; j++) {
                int A = reader.nextInt();
                int B = reader.nextInt();
                union(A, B, parent, rank);
            }
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> histo = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            for (int j = 1; j < parent.length; j++) {
                int root = parent[j];
                if (!histo.containsKey(root)) {
                    histo.put(root, 1);
                }
                else {
                    histo.put(root, histo.get(root) + 1);
                }

            }
            int max = Collections.max(histo.values());
            System.out.println(max);
        }
    }

    // UFDS find
    static int find(int x, int[] parent) {

        if (parent[x]!= x) {
            parent[x] = find(parent[x], parent);
        }

        return parent[x];
    }

    // UFDS union
    static void union(int x, int y, int[] parent, int[] rank) {
        int xRoot = find(x, parent);
        int yRoot = find(y, parent);

        if (xRoot == yRoot) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (rank[xRoot] < rank[yRoot]) {
                parent[xRoot] = yRoot;
            }

            else if (rank[yRoot] < rank[xRoot]) {
                parent[yRoot] = xRoot;
            }

            else {
                parent[yRoot] = xRoot;
                for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
                    if (parent[i] == yRoot) {
                        parent[i] = xRoot;
                    }
                }
                rank[xRoot] = rank[xRoot] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works for the sample input, but when passing it through an online judge system that runs it through hundreds of test cases, it tells me wrong output. Not sure where my error might be? Seems like a simple UFDS problem to me.

Comment: Try input `1`, `4 3`, `1 2`, `3 4`, `4 1`. Result should be that friend chain `3-4-1-2` is size 4, but your code prints 3.

Comment: @Andreas I updated the code at the very last else function to fix it; still tells me wrong answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop you put in `union` ruins the performance.  Just take it out.

In the histogram loop, you need `int root = find(j,parent);`

Your code throws an exception when `numcitizens` is zero.

Fix that stuff and your code will work, I think.

Here are a couple extra hints:

- I always union by size instead of union by rank.  It has the same complexity, and the size is often useful.  In this case you wouldn't need to build the histogram because you'd have the size of every root right there.
- I use a single `int[]` array for the data structure.  If a value *v* is >=0, then it's a root set with that size (0 means there's no set or empty set at that index).  Otherwise *~v* is a link to the parent set.  I recently used that structure in this answer: [Algorithm: use union find to count number of islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284043/algorithm-use-union-find-to-count-number-of-islands/55286369#55286369)

Answer (score 0):

The number of friends each person has is not the `parent`array.Rank of each person
is the height of tree representing by the set i.e the number of friend that person have.
so use `root=rank[j]+1` in the for loop for counting the max friends.

```
int max=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int r:rank){
    max=Math.max(max,r+1);
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: Rank is the height. I'm not trying to get the largest depth, I'm trying to get the largest number of nodes

Comment: In this case height is also the number of nodes

Comment: How? A tree like 3-4-1-2, without path compression, has height 3 but 4 nodes.

Comment: But the rank is three i.e 3 has three frinds

Comment: Yeah but I don't want the rank, I want the number of nodes in that tree. The question is asking for the largest group of friends, not who has the most friends

Comment: so you have to add 1

Comment: But how is that any different from just finding out using the parent array?

Comment: because parent[i] gives you the parent of the person i not the number of friends he has

Comment: The parent array stores the root node in all of a tree's children. I'm using a histogram to keep count then I find the max.